# How do I turn a char bubblesort into a string bubblesort by string length

Tags: c, sorting, multidimensional-array, bubble-sort, function-definition

I have written a basic bubble sorting program that uses given input from a predetermined array or characters, but I want to change it so I can sort strings. Also I want to not sort it alphabetically, but sort them by string length.

my source.c

```
void sort(char array[], int size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < size - i - 1; j++) {
            if (array[j] > array[j + 1]) {
                int temp = array[j];
                array[j] = array[j + 1];
                array[j + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}

void printArray(char array[], int size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        printf("%c ", array[i]); //%c -> %s
    }
}

int main(void) {

    char array[] = { 'F', 'A', 'D', 'B', 'C' };
        //char string[][] = { "hey", "Hello", "awesome" };


    int size = sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]);

    sort(array, size);
    printArray(array, size);

    return 0;
}
```

I had tried to make the `char array[];` in the `int main(void)` a string array as `char string[][];`
and tried make any changes accordingly but I keep failing (building errors). I also don't understand how I should change it to sort by string length and not alphabet order

Comment: hmmm... it would make more sense to post the failing code instead of posting some working code that ain't doing what you want

Comment: `char string[][]` array requires you to accept pointer to array in the functions: `void f(size_t rows, size_t columns, char(*)[columns])` or alternatively `void f(size_t rows, size_t columns, char[rows][columns])`, which actually is *identical* (outermost dimension decays to pointer). If you rather want to operate on `void f(size_t size, char const* strings[])` you need an array of pointers, too...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters pay attention to that your function implementation is inefficient because its nested loops will be executed many times for an already sorted array. That is the function does not take into account that a part of the array (or the whole array) is already sorted.

If you want to sort an array by some condition then you should declare the function with one more parameter that will specify a comparison function similarly to the standard C function `qsort`.

So supplying different functions you can sort the same array using different rules of comparisons of its element.

You always should write more general functions.

Here is a demonstration program that shows how such a function that implements the bubble sort method can be written for two-dimensional character arrays.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

enum { N = 6 };

void bubble_sort( char s[][N], size_t n, int cmp( const void *, const void * ) )
{
    for (size_t sorted = 1; !( n < 2 ); n = sorted)
    {
        for (size_t j = sorted = 1; j < n; j++)
        {
            if (cmp( &s[j], &s[j - 1] ) < 0)
            {
                char tmp[N];
                strcpy( tmp, s[j] );
                strcpy( s[j], s[j - 1] );
                strcpy( s[j - 1], tmp );

                sorted = j;
            }
        }
    }
}

static int by_length( const void *a, const void *b )
{
    char ( *s1 )[N] = ( char( * )[N] )a;
    char( *s2 )[N] = ( char( * )[N] )b;

    size_t n1 = strlen( *s1 );
    size_t n2 = strlen( *s2 );

    return ( n2 < n1 ) - ( n1 < n2 );
}

static int lexicographically( const void *a, const void *b )
{
    char( *s1 )[N] = ( char( * )[N] )a;
    char( *s2 )[N] = ( char( * )[N] )b;

    return strcmp( *s1, *s2 );
}

int main( void )
{

    char s[][N] =
    {
        "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten"
    };

    const size_t M = sizeof( s ) / sizeof( *s );

    for (size_t i = 0; i < M; i++)
    {
        printf( "\"%s\" ", s[i] );
    }

    putchar( '\n' );

    bubble_sort( s, M, by_length );

    for (size_t i = 0; i < M; i++)
    {
        printf( "\"%s\" ", s[i] );
    }

    putchar( '\n' );

    bubble_sort( s, M, lexicographically );

    for (size_t i = 0; i < M; i++)
    {
        printf( "\"%s\" ", s[i] );
    }

    putchar( '\n' );
}
```

The program output is

```
"One" "Two" "Three" "Four" "Five" "Six" "Seven" "Eight" "Nine" "Ten"
"One" "Two" "Six" "Ten" "Four" "Five" "Nine" "Three" "Seven" "Eight"
"Eight" "Five" "Four" "Nine" "One" "Seven" "Six" "Ten" "Three" "Two"
```

You can write even a more general function if your compiler supports variable length arrays.

For example in this case the function declaration can look like

```
void bubble_sort( size_t m, size_t n, char s[m][n], int cmp( const void *, const void * ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `sort()` and `printArray()` to take an array of strings.  Then change the compare function to use `strlen()` to find the same.  You could pre-preprocess the array to obtain all the sizes once instead of n^2 times.  It doesn't matter with small input.  I reverse sorted it by size (`<`) as the input array is already sorted by increasing size:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void sort(size_t size, char *array[size]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < size - i - 1; j++) {
            if (strlen(array[j]) < strlen(array[j + 1])) {
                char *temp = array[j];
                array[j] = array[j + 1];
                array[j + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}

void printArray(size_t size, char *array[size]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        printf("%s ", array[i]); //%c -> %s
    }
}

int main(void) {
    char *array[] = { "hey", "Hello", "awesome" };
    size_t size = sizeof array / *sizeof array[0];
    sort(size, array);
    printArray(size, array);
}
```

Example run:

```
awesome Hello hey
```

Comment: how would I import text lines from a input.txt file into the string array in the `int main(void)` ? i've only found examples for 2d arrays

Comment: Open a new question if you need help with it.  The two general approaches is to fix the upper size then malloc an array and fread/fread into that array. The other option is to define  a chunk size, say, 4k, then malloc the initial 4k, then in 2nd time realloc 2 * 4k in the before you read the next chunk.